# Get each text from collection of span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three spans in one div, in console:

```
$(".cnt_step_2 .regions_list li span")
[
<span>​text0​</span>​
, 
<span>​text1</span>​
, 
<span>​text2</span>​
]
```

I want to get each text from every span

for first span I try to get like this:

```
$(".cnt_step_2 .regions_list li span")[0]
<span>text0</span.
```

now I want to extract only text

```
$(".cnt_step_2 .regions_list li span")[0].text()
   TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

also I try

```
$(".cnt_step_2 .regions_list li span")[0].html()
    TypeError: undefined is not a function

$(".cnt_step_2 .regions_list li span")[0].val()
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

How extract the text from the span?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the jQuery element, `[0]` gets the native DOM element, which has no `text()` method.

```
$(".cnt_step_2 .regions_list li span").eq(0).text()
```

#### EDIT:

The error doesn't really seem to be related to that code at all.
If jQuery wasn't included, you'd get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

and if it was included, and you got the error from the `[0]`, you'd get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
```

and you're getting

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

which indicates that you're trying to call a function that isn't really a function, like this

```
var test = undefined;
test();
```

would give you that error.

Comment: your code give same error
TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: @Alex - Did you include jQuery, and are you sure it's loaded properly.

Comment: I use jquery-1.5.2.min.js

Comment: Then try using jQuery instead of $ -> `jQuery(".cnt_step_2 .regions_list li span").eq(0).text()`

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="target">
    aa <span>text0</span> aa
    bb <span>text1</span> bb
    cc<span>text2</span> cc
</div>
```

JS:

```
var spanText = '';
$('.target span').each(function(){
    spanText += $(this).text();
});
alert(spanText);
```

Working [JSFiddle Example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/iamruss/s35WS/1/)

In case you need indexed access to a particular element, use this approach:

```
var spanText0 = $($('.target span')[0]).text();
alert(spanText0);
var spanText1 = $($('.target span')[1]).text();
alert(spanText1);
var spanText2 = $($('.target span')[2]).text();
alert(spanText2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iamruss/8HTBq/1/

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do with *each* text? jQuery handles everything you want to do... it does not matter how many spans there are (works even when there is no span at all).

For example if you like to concatenate the texts go like this:

```
var text = '';
$('.cnt_step_2 .regions_list li span').each(function() {
  text += $(this).text() + ', ';
});

// text = "text0, text1, text2, "
```

Bad example with the last comma, but it should only show how it works. The jQuery selector matches *all* your spans. With `each()` we iterate over the elements. Inside the function `this` is the DOM element, so `$(this)` is a jQuery object. By calling `text()` you get the text inside the element.

If there is HTML inside the `span` you can use `html()` instead if you wish to keep the HTML.